# Convert data frame containing coordinates of polygons to sf

Tags: r, geometry, polygon, r-sf

I am a beginner with `sf` package and I am having some difficulties converting my data frame into a `sf` object.

I have a data frame containing coordinates of polygons in each row. These coordinates are in a single column.

Here is an example of the structure of my data frame :

```r
dat <- tibble::tribble(
    ~code,    ~geometry,
    "MIE",    list(c(1.24, 45), c(1.25, 45), c(1.25, 46), c(1.24, 45)),
    "MIS",    list(c(1.23, 44), c(1.23, 45), c(1.24, 45), c(1.23, 44))
    )
```

I want to make a sf object from this data frame but R can't recognize the geometry column.

I tried list formats and functions like `st_sf()`, `st_geometry()`, `st_polygon()` but without success.

Trying `st_sf(dat)` returns:

Error in `st_sf(dat)` :

```
Error in st_sf(dat) : no simple features geometry column present
```

Trying `st_polygon(dat$geometry)` returns :

```
Error in vapply(x, ncol, 0L) : values must be length 1,
  but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0
```

Is there any way to convert my data frame into a sf object ?

I'm working with `R` version 3.6.0.

Comment: It will be easier to help if the data sample is in a format we can paste into a script, such as by calling `dput`. It's also easier to help if we can see the code that didn't work—how exactly did you try using `st_sf`?

Comment: I tried `st_geometry(dat) <- st_sf(st_polygon(dat$geometry))` and `dat.sf <- st_sf(dat)`. Also, I saw that sometimes geometry can be wrap twice in lists like `list(list(c(x1,y1),c(x2,y2)))` but that doesn't change anything. I tried with `st_sfc` too, but I am not sure to understand the difference with `st_sf` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always struggle with doing this `sf` transformation too, because it's not straight forward.

The first step (and hard part) is to build a `st_object` (here `st_polygon`) for each individual geometry represented.

To do that, convert each existing `list` into a `matrix`. Once each polygon representation is a n-row `matrix` (one row for each point) we convert the matrix to a one element `list` to feed into `st_polygon()`. Now `dat$geometry` is a list appropriately classed of `POLYGONS`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate(geometry = map(geometry,
                        ~ do.call(rbind, .) %>% # make each list a matrix
                          list() %>% # st_polygon() requires a list
                          st_polygon()
                    )
         ) %>% 
  st_as_sf()
```

Then the final step is to call `st_as_sf()` on the entire data frame. It will auto-detect the now properly formatted `geometry` column and produce a nice new `sf` object for you. Happy mapping!

*EDIT*: If you want to build polygons with holes, the process is similar. `st_polygon()` will process a multi-element list as if the the first element is the polygon and the remaining elements are holes in the first. It does require that you use `map` twice, because you still need to build a matrix out of each list element, but need keep the lists of grouped matrixs together for processing the holes.

```
dat2 <- tibble::tribble( ~code, ~geometry, "MIE", list(list(c(1.24, 45), c(1.25, 45), c(1.25, 46), c(1.24, 45)), list(c(1.245,45.5), c(1.246,45.7), c(1.245,45.5))) )

 dat %>%
  mutate(geometry = map(dat$geometry,
                        ~ map(.,
                          ~ do.call(rbind, .) # make each list a matrix
                          ) %>% 
                        st_polygon()
                        )
  ) %>% 
  st_as_sf()
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Do you have any idea to handle polygons with holes ? For example : 
```r
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~code,    ~geometry,
  "MIE",    list(list(c(1.24, 45), c(1.25, 45), c(1.25, 46), c(1.24, 45)), 
                 list(c(1.245,45.5), c(1.246,45.7), c(1.245,45.5)))
)
```
The polygon is the first list, the hole the second one