# tibbles and lists - r wrangling dplyr

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tibble

I am trying to convert a bunch of points to polygons.

I found a nice example of what I'm trying to accomplish here: [Convert data frame containing coordinates of polygons to sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258655/convert-data-frame-containing-coordinates-of-polygons-to-sf)

I'd like to try their method, but I don't have the skills to go from:

```
# how I see the points after read_csv - simply 3 columns lon, lat, id
df<-tibble(
  lon = c(-119.036,-119.002,-119.010,-119.044,-119.036,-119.002,-118.968,-118.977,-119.010,-119.002),
  lat = c(23.097,23.105,23.136,23.128,23.097,23.105,23.112,23.143,23.136,23.105),
  id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
 )
```

to:

```
# how i want the info organized to work off of stkoverflow eg linked above
df<-tibble::tribble(
  ~id,     ~geometry,
  "1",    list(c(-119.036,23.097), c(-119.002,23.105), c(-119.010,23.136), c(-119.044,23.128), c(-119.036,23.097)),
  "2",    list(c(-119.002,23.105),c(-118.968,23.112),c(-118.977,23.143), c(-119.010,23.136), c(-119.002,23.105))
)
```

If possible, I'd like to do with dplyr commands.

Comment: FYI, the use of the word `geometry`, the premise of paired longitude/latitude, and the way you're trying to organize this is mildly mimicking `s`imple `f`eatures (aka the `sf` package). Depending on what you're trying to do with this `geometry` column, you might want to research `sf` and all that it can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
out <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(geometry = list(Map(c, lon, lat)))
out
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#      id geometry  
#   <dbl> <list>    
# 1     1 <list [5]>
# 2     2 <list [5]>
```

Comparison with your second frame (I named `df2`):

```r
str(out)
# tibble [2 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  $ id      : num [1:2] 1 2
#  $ geometry:List of 2
#   ..$ :List of 5
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   ..$ :List of 5
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
str(df2)
# tibble [2 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  $ id      : chr [1:2] "1" "2"
#  $ geometry:List of 2
#   ..$ :List of 5
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   ..$ :List of 5
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
#   .. ..$ : num [1:2] -119 23.1
```

Comment: It can be further simplified to `df %>% summarise(geometry = list(Map(c, lon, lat)), .by = id)`

Comment: Yeah, I keep going back and forth with using `group_by` versus `.by=`. I think I am leaning towards `group_by` when there are multiple steps (more than a single `mutate` or `summarize` call), since the group-calculation is not zero cost, and it'd be better to preserve it across multiple calls. Expressions like the above are clearly easy enough to use `.by=` instead ... though I still get bitten every now and then by somebody on an older version of `dplyr` and who does not understand the changes/issues involved. (Ergo the turmoil.)

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data.frame and then reshape lat and lon into a matrix and then split the matrix by row to create your list of pairs. For example

```
df %>% 
  summarize(geometry = list(cbind(lon, lat) |> split(1:length(lat)) |> unname()), .by=id)
```

This returns

```
tibble(
  id = c(1, 2), 
  geometry = list(
   list(c(-119.036, 23.097), c(-119.002, 23.105), c(-119.01, 23.136), c(-119.044, 23.128), c(-119.036, 23.097)), 
   list(c(-119.002, 23.105), c(-118.968, 23.112), c(-118.977,23.143), c(-119.01, 23.136), c(-119.002, 23.105))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use that result with anything that expects `sf` or `sfc` objects, you can just convert your data.frame / tibble to `sf` with `st_as_sf()`. The problem in the linked question was about wrangling a nested list column, it's not a step you need to take if you already have a normal rectangular and flat data.frame with lat/lon columns.

With your sample data:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)

df <- 
  tibble(
    lon = c(-119.036,-119.002,-119.010,-119.044,-119.036,-119.002,-118.968,-118.977,-119.010,-119.002),
    lat = c(23.097,23.105,23.136,23.128,23.097,23.105,23.112,23.143,23.136,23.105),
    id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
    )  

polygons <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "WGS84") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(do_union = FALSE) %>% 
  st_cast("POLYGON")
polygons
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -119.044 ymin: 23.097 xmax: -118.968 ymax: 23.143
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      id                                                                 geometry
#>   <dbl>                                                            <POLYGON [°]>
#> 1     1 ((-119.036 23.097, -119.002 23.105, -119.01 23.136, -119.044 23.128, -1…
#> 2     2 ((-119.002 23.105, -118.968 23.112, -118.977 23.143, -119.01 23.136, -1…

ggplot(polygons) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = as.factor(id)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>